# Unable to launch app when removed from recent apps when foreground service is running Android

Tags: android

I have implemented a foreground service with a notification for my existing android project.

**Problem**: I remove the app from the "recent app" when the foreground service is running and its notification is visible. Later, I try to launch the app by clicking on the app icon. A black screen appears for a second and the app is not launched.

The app is stuck in this state until I got to app settings and force close the application.

Foreground Service:

```
public class FileSyncService extends Service {

    private static final int FILE_SYNC_SERVICE_ID = 901;
    public static final String FILE_SYNC_SERVICE_ACTION_STOP = "StopFileSyncService";
    public static final String FILE_SYNC_SERVICE_ACTION_START = "StartFileSyncService";

    @Inject
    private FilePushManager filePushManager;

    @Inject
    private NotificationController notificationController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Logger.d("[FileSyncService][onCreate]");
        BootstrappingManager.getInstance().getInjector().injectMembers(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Logger.d("[FileSyncService][onStartCommand]");

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(FILE_SYNC_SERVICE_ACTION_STOP)) {
            Logger.d("[FileSyncService][onStartCommand] stopSelf");
            stopForegroundService();

        } else {
            Logger.d("[FileSyncService][onStartCommand] startForeground");
            startForeground(FILE_SYNC_SERVICE_ID, notificationController.createFileSyncNotification());
            filePushManager.startFilePush();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Logger.d("[FileSyncService] onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void stopForegroundService() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE);
        } else {
            stopForeground(true);
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Methods to start stop service:

```
 public static void startFileSyncService(Context context) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, FileSyncService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(FileSyncService.FILE_SYNC_SERVICE_ACTION_START);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Logger.d("[MandatoryUtils][startFileSyncService] foreground");
            try {
                context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Logger.e("[MandatoryUtils][startFileSyncService] unable to start File Sync Service", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.e("[MandatoryUtils][startFileSyncService] unable to start File Sync Service Exception", e);
            }
        } else {
            Logger.d("[MandatoryUtils][startFileSyncService] ");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

    public static void stopFileSyncService(Context context) {
        Logger.d("[MandatoryUtils][stopFileSyncService]");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, FileSyncService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(FileSyncService.FILE_SYNC_SERVICE_ACTION_STOP);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

Launcher Activity:

```
 <application
        android:name="net.activities.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/scl"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:manageSpaceActivity="net.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:theme="@style/ContentLibraryTheme"
        tools:replace="allowBackup, android:theme">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

        <activity
                android:name="net.activities.SplashActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:exported="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Splash"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
...
```

Comment: How about returning `START_NOT_STICKY`?

Comment: @Zain START_NOT_STICKY also gives the same results.